# ¿Cómo pasar la información que contenga un textarea a un div editable jquery?

Tags: jquery

La información que tenga el `textarea` automáticamente debe pasar también al `div editable`, y viceversa es decir si yo llego escribir en div también debe pasar en el `textarea` ambos deben tener una conexión, por ahora dispongo de lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```js
$(function() {
    let EditHTML = $("#detail");
    EditHTML.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#editor").val(EditHTML.html());
        $("#editor").keyup();
    });
});
```

```css
#editor {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="detail">Esta información debe pasar al div editable y viceversa, es decir todo cambio que se realicen tanto en el textarea con el div editable en ambos se debe mostrar </textarea>
<div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle está en el val y el html, también puedes tener dos funciones para poder lograr escribir lo mismo en los dos elementos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var EditHTML = $("#detail");
            $("#editor").html(EditHTML.val());
        });
    
$(function() {    
  var EditHTML = $("#detail");
    EditHTML.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#editor").html(EditHTML.val());
    });
});

$(function() {
  var EditHTML = $("#editor");
    EditHTML.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#detail").val(EditHTML.html());
    });
});
```

```css
#editor {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="detail">Esta información debe pasar al div editable y viceversa, es decir todo cambio que se realicen tanto en el textarea con el div editable en ambos se debe mostrar </textarea>
<div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: alguna forma de que se muestre al instante sin tener que dar enter en el textarea ??

Comment: Puedes verificar que cuando el documento este listo añada el contenido del textarea. Edite la respuesta

Comment: Aquí funciona muy bien pero desde mi código igual me toca dar un enter en el textarea para visualizar los datos, creo que a lo mejor es por que los datos los estoy cargando con ajax en un modal... Algúna manera de que al dar click en el div editable este envié un enter o un espacio automáticamente al textarea ?

Comment: Desde el Ajax, después de cargar los datos al $("#detail"), puedes pasar el valor a $("#editor") con $("#editor").html($("#detail").val())

Comment: Aquí lo debo agregar verdad? `.done(function(data){
            $('#detail').val(data.detail);
            $('#insert').val("Update");  
            $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeIn(350);
        }).fail(function(){
            alert( "Ajax Request fail" );
        })` al final de todo dentro de `done`

Comment: Así es, dentro de la función done, cualquier lugar después de la instrucción $('#detail').val(data.detail);